# problem in accessing the bullet M2 hi-power?

Tags: networking

I am using the bullet M2 as a bridge between my router and wireless clients

There is an issue to access the bullet I plugged the LAN cable in to my pc and wants to access the  Bullet to change the configuration but I am unable to access it.

The ether net connection shows unidentified connection when I connect bullet to my pc via LAN but when I plug in to router it works fine

Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet your PC is set for DHCP and not getting an address when connected the bullet to configure it.  Often you need to statically set an address in the to talk to these home network bridges.

Find the manual for it and read it carefully.  Im sure the answer is there.

Comment: nop i have set my pc ip on same domain as for bullet as 192.168.1.25 for pc and 192.168.1.11 for bullet